# Is there anything like Windows systeminfo on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, system-information

On Windows the [systeminfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/systeminfo) command is a quick way to get system information from the shell.

Is there any command like that on macOS?

Comment: What exact info do you need. Try From Apple menu About this Mac and hit the System Report Button

Answer (score 4):

Both `system_profiler` and `sysctl` provide copious amounts of system information, which you can narrow down using grep, depending on what it is you're after.

Answer (score 3):

The `networksetup` command can be used to get a lot of system information related to the network and network hardware. For non-network system information, use `system_profiler` or `sysctl -a -h` (other options for the `sysctl` command provide the system information in a different format).